# Server Side Rendering with Nginx outputs HTML strings

Tags: node.js, express, nginx, server-side-rendering

I have a `vue-ssr` project, not using `nuxt.js`. And the server is `express`.
Project ran at port 3000.

When **not using nginx**, visited ip:3000, the page **worked well**.

When **using nginx**, visited my domain, I still could get HTML strings, but **the strings were not rendered**, like that:

(I don't have enought reputation to post images.)

[html strings.png](https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/s!AuTsOc4FZKrKhAlABLFPpyV1058U/root/content)

And the request and response headers like that:

[request and response headers.png](https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/shares/s!AuTsOc4FZKrKhApRmMgvixxGb2EB/root/content)

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
  server_name mydomain;
  root /my/path;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

I've tried the config introduced in [nuxt.js documents](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy), but didn't worked either.

Comment: My bad. I did not post full configs. I deleted `add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;` and now it works. But I don't think this is a correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

If removing the `nosniff` header fixes the problem, that would be an indication that for some reason `express` is not sending the right mime types with your responses.

You could check that by hitting express directly and examining the headers it is returning, e.g.:

```
curl -D - -o /dev/null http://localhost:3000
```

If it's NOT returning text/html, it could be a sign you're accidentally breaking the default mime type somewhere in your application code.

Comment: I ran the commands, and the `Content-Type` was `text/html; charset=UTF-8`. Does that mean there is something wrong with nginx conf？ But I didn't modify other nginx confs like `nginx.conf`.